# PROCEDURE com média

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Create table FUNCIONARIOS (num number, nome varchar2(30), custo_hora number);
Create table PROJETOS (cod number, nome varchar2(15), custo_acc number(10,2), horas_acc(10,2));
Create table ALOCACAO_REAL (semana number, horas_trab number, cod_proj number, num_func number);
Create table ALOCACAO_PREV (horas_prev_sem number, cod_proj number, num_func number);
```

Preciso criar uma `procedure` que: verifique e aponte quais funcionários estão trabalhando em cada projeto na média das 4 últimas semanas, acima da quantidade de horas previstas para aquele funcionário dentro daquele  Projeto.

Cheguei neste ponto, mas está dando um erro:

```
create or replace procedure func_horas_excedentes as
/* set serveroutput on; */
begin
    for x in (select * from ALOCACAO_PREV)
    loop
        x.num_func;
        x.cod_proj;
        x.horas_prev_sem;
        select max semana into ult_semana from ALOCACAO_REAL where num_func = x.num;
        select avg (horas_trab) into media from ALOCACAO_REAL where semana > (ult_semana -4);
        select * from ALOCACAO_REAL where num_func = x.num_func and cod_proj = x.cod_proj and media > x.horas_prev_sem;
        /* dbms_output.put_line ('Func: ','Projeto: ','Media Horas Trabalhadas: ','Horas Previstas: ',|| x.num_func, x.cod_proj, media, x.horas_prev_sem); */
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
```

Erro:

> Errors: PROCEDURE FUNC_HORAS_EXCEDENTES Line/Col: 12/13 PL/SQL: SQL
> Statement ignored Line/Col: 12/17 PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or
> invalid option Line/Col: 13/104 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "|"
> when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current
> exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge
> time timestamp interval    date       pipe    
> <an alternatively

Com "`set server`..." antes do `begin`, da mais erro.

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Estude a cláusula `HAVING`, ela será útil para a solução de seu problema.

Comment: select avg (horas_trab) as media from ALOCACAO_REAL having semana > (ult_semana -4);

Comment: A Procedure que roda ou compila é esta mesmo ?! Este "select * from ALOCACAO_REAL" sem INTO não funciona em plsql , uma coisa sendo ORACLE não coloque "tag" MySql SqlServer etc ...